# What is the difference between DataTemplate and DataContext in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I can set the relationship between View Model and view through following `DataContext` syntax:

```
 <UserControl.DataContext>
    <view_model:MainMenuModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

And I can also set the relationship between View Model and view through following `DataTemplate` syntax:

```
    <DataTemplate
        DataType="{x:Type viewModel:UserViewModel}">
        <view:UserView />
    </DataTemplate>
```

What is the difference between the two? Is the second [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language) not setting the data context of a view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second XAML defines a *template* that can be used to display an object of type `viewModel:UserViewModel`.  It doesn't set data for anything but, if a `ContentPresenter` is asked to display an object of that type, it will use your template.

Your first XAML is setting the `DataContext` property of your control.  It defines that any bindings you perform within that scope will use the `DataContext` as the root of the binding (unless explicitly overriden).  For a simple example of `DataContext` at work, compare these two (both assume that "s" is the `System` namespace):

```
<StackPanel>  
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day, Source={x:Static s:DateTime.Now}}" />
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Month, Source={x:Static s:DateTime.Now}}" />
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Year, Source={x:Static s:DateTime.Now}}" />
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static s:DateTime.Now}}">  
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}" />
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Month}" />
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Year}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Both `StackPanels` will render identically, but the second is more easily reused.  (E.g.: you only have to change the binding in one place if you wanted to display a different date.)

Comment: Hi Peter,Ben Thanks to you all for the reply.

I am wondering if I can set the datacontext and datatemplate of a control to the same view model ?

Comment: @Ashish: you can set the DataContext to the ViewModel itself, but you set the DataTemplate to a template that *displays* the ViewModel - not to the viewmodel itself.

Answer (score 2):

The `DataContext` of a `FrameworkElement` is what the element is bound to.  It is fundamentally of type `object`.  In the MVVM pattern, this is most frequently the ViewModel object, but it need not be.  It is simply some context information you want to apply to that `FrameworkElement`.  It does not directly affect the visual representation, by itself.

When WPF wants to display some object that doesn't have it's own visual representation (e.g. isn't descended from `UIElement`, it will look to see if a corresponding `DataTemplate` exists to define how it should present that data.  In your example, you have said that the `UserViewModel` class should be presented using the `UserView` control, but you have not actually created either the `UserViewModel` or `UserView`.

These two concepts often go together.  For example, imagine you had an `ObservableCollection<object>` which had in it a `Foo` and a `Bar` object.  You could define different `DataTemplate`s for `Foo` and `Bar`.  Then you could bind your collection into an `ItemsControl`.  Each object in the control would get a visual representation based on the appropriate `DataTemplate` from its type.

Another simple example: if you have a property on your ViewModel named `DisplayObject` and you simply want it to appear with whatever `DataTemplate` you have defined, you can use the `ContentPresenter` control:

```
<ContentPresenter DataContext="{Binding DisplayObject}"/>
```

Again, this results in WPF looking up the correct Template for the type and using that to construct a representation.